# How can I find the Probability?

Tags: probability

I'm working on statistic homework and Im stumped on a problem.

Problem:

- There are 28 chocolates in a box
- 5 are filled with nuts
- 13 with caramel
- 10 are solid chocolates

You randomly pick than you select another at random, what is the probability that you will select 2 solid chocolates in a row?

a.) 5/378
b.) 5/42
c.) 45/392
d.) 25/196

I Thought it was right to do the following, take the total
of solid chocolates 10 and divide by the total of chocolate 28

10/28 then after take one out and multiply it to the first one 9/27

(10/28) * (9/27) I got .118

However I tried converting it and it did not give me any of the possible answers, What am I doing wrong? Could someone Please lend me your expertise? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: simplify both fractions and look at the result.

Comment: Nice sense of humour. :P

Comment: Wow... So I should simplify every-time I finish the arithmetic?? How did I not see that, Thank you very much.